# Installing Bluetooth Driver for EP-AC1661

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, bluetooth

I am using EP-AC1661 WiFi and bluetooth adapter. According to their website the driver is supported only for kernel version 2.6 .I am trying to install the drivers on ubuntu 18.04 with a kernel version 5.0.0.29-generic

when I run the command

```
sudo make install -s
```

I get an error

```
    rtk_coex.c:2532:2 :error: implicit declaration of function 'init_timer'; did you mean 'init_timers'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
init_timer(&btrtl_coex.polling_timer)
```

any pointers in how do I fix this issue?

Edit1: The result of lsusb

```
:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:c820 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0b23 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2137 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1307:0330 Transcend Information, Inc. 63-in-1 Multi-Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 0424:5537 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

The result of tail -f /var/log/syslog

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
Sep 23 16:17:42 blue kernel: [ 5578.720943] usb 2-6: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue kernel: [ 5578.877878] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c820, bcdDevice= 2.00
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue kernel: [ 5578.877881] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue kernel: [ 5578.877883] usb 2-6: Product: 802.11ac NIC
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue kernel: [ 5578.877885] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Realtek
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue kernel: [ 5578.877887] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: FF
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-6"
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue upowerd[1164]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-6
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue kernel: [ 5578.981975] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC=bc:ae:c5:1a:0e:f1:00:bb:c1:75:7a:46:08:00 SRC=10.1.10.68 DST=10.1.10.121 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=49755 PROTO=UDP SPT=8610 DPT=8612 LEN=40 
Sep 23 16:17:43 blue kernel: [ 5578.992093] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC=bc:ae:c5:1a:0e:f1:00:bb:c1:75:7a:46:08:00 SRC=10.1.10.68 DST=10.1.10.121 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56262 PROTO=UDP SPT=8610 DPT=8612 LEN=40
```

Edit2:Result of usb-device

```
usb-devices 
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=05 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=c820 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11ac NIC
S:  SerialNumber=FF
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 6 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8821cu
```

Comment: It is unclear - what is EP-AC1661? How do you connect it? Do you see it in `lsusb` / `lsusb`? How does current kernel react on insertion of this device (see `tail -f /var/log/syslog`)?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` It was generous of the manufacturer to provide a 15-year-old driver! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Noted. I have added the results of those commands

Comment: @chili555 ^^^^^

Comment: You can install the driver by referring to the duplicate. Post back if you get stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ubuntu 18.04 - dlink dwa171 (revC) shows as a memory stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164356/ubuntu-18-04-dlink-dwa171-revc-shows-as-a-memory-stick)

Comment: @chili555 I think that is for the wifi module and not the bluetooth. I used that to solve the problem with the wifi driver. My question was more geared towards the bluetooth driver. Should I change the question to specify that or should just mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Oops! I sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=` terminal command.

Comment: This device should be supported. Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

Answer (score 0):

This bluetooth device is supported by Linux kernel as you can see in `drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c`.

```
/* Realtek Bluetooth devices */
    { USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x0bda, 0xe0, 0x01, 0x01),
      .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
```

The meaning of `(0x0bda, 0xe0, 0x01, 0x01)` is exactly what you have in

```
Vendor=0bda  Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01
```

You have a combo Wi-Fi + BT device, both parts are visible in `usb-devices`

```
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 6 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8821cu
```

is the Wi-Fi device. It loads `rtl8821cu` driver successfully.

```
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

is the BT device. It doesn't load `btusb` driver for some reason.

The reasons might be:

1. Kernel doesn't properly handle combo devices. This can be tested by blacklisting `rtl8821cu`. It should load `btusb`. If this is the case, it is a kernel bug that should be reported.
2. You already installed some driver that blacklists `btusb`, but doesn't work.

If you get `btusb` loading, you need to make sure there is firmware in `lib/firmware/rtl_bt`. The file is called `rtl8821a_config.bin`.

This file hasn't been added to `linux-firmware` yet, but you can find it in the old driver that you downloaded previuosly, that didn't install.

I see a file there in `linux/2017.../BT/2017...BT_ANDROID/rtkbt/system/etc/firmware/rtl8821a_config`

Try to rename it to `rtl8821a_config.bin` and copy to `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt`.

If this file works, I'll send it upstream.

Comment: So I now added the bluetooth module in another linux environment. I ran the same command. This is the result. `If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=eo(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb`  `If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=eo(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb` I see the btusb module is now loaded under lsmod but hciconfig does not list a BD Address

Comment: Look into `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`.

Comment: So in dmesg i do get `hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin failed with error -2` is this the problem?

Comment: Exatctly. I updated the answer. I am looking for this file.

Comment: So now I got a `hci0:download fw command failed (-110)` So I followed the similar procedure to copy rtl8821a_fw.bin I still get the same error `hci0:command 0xfc20 tx timeout` and `hci0:download fw command failed (-110)`

Comment: `rtl8821a_fw.bin` seems to be already there. Anyway it seems that nobody really checked if the device is properly supported  by Linux. I suggest getting another BT device unless you really want to find a way to add a proper support.