# rtl8821cu driver for ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, realtek-wireless, dkms

I'm running ubuntu 19.10 with LXDE desktop. My kernel version is 5.6.0. I've tried installing DKMS using Additional Drivers but after reboot the laptop wifi adapter showing as UNCLAIMED in `lshw -c network` output. What else should I do to get it working?

- **EDIT-1**: secure boot is disabled in BIOS/firmware.
- **EDIT-2**: I followed this link: [ubuntu 18.04 - dlink dwa171 (revC) shows as a memory stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164356/ubuntu-18-04-dlink-dwa171-revc-shows-as-a-memory-stick)

  but after running `./dkms-install.sh` I got this error:
  [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu 18.04 - dlink dwa171 (revC) shows as a memory stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164356/ubuntu-18-04-dlink-dwa171-revc-shows-as-a-memory-stick)

Comment: Thanks, after running "./dkms-install.sh" I got this error: "Your kernel headers for kernel 5.6.0-...rc5-generic cannot be found." It asks me to install linux-headers-5.6.0-...rc5-generic package. How can I install it? Thanks again

Comment: You can probably install it from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/. Also, I am not sure it will work with 5.6, as it is just not practical to support any kernel there is.

Comment: FYI:  You're not using the lubuntu desktop; 18.04 was the last which used LXDE, Lubuntu since 18.10 supports only LXQt packages, and because LXDE relies on GTK+2 libs, it'll [possibly disappear in the very near future (as GTK2 libs are depreciated)

Comment: @mikewhatever, on which kernel version I can install the driver?

Comment: @mikewhatever, I did what the link you've sent to me but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did run `apt update && apt upgrade` and then finally kernel module installed on my machine successfully.