# AC600 802.11ac wireless USB not working

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am trying to get a [usb wireless device](https://www.amazon.co.uk/802-11ac-Wireless-Network-receiver-10-5-10-13/dp/B07YK3SN86/) working on ubuntu, sadly when it gets plugged in it seems to come up as a storage device rather than an interface.

I have tried installing numerous drivers from many different sources (to list a some):

- [TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Installing rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.0_6952.20130315.tar.gz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491263/installing-rtl8812au-linux-v4-2-0-6952-20130315-tar-gz)
- [Command to rebuild all DKMS modules for all installed kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53364/command-to-rebuild-all-dkms-modules-for-all-installed-kernels)

This is the output of the `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

`dmesg` output on plugging in the usb:

```
[  +0.000666] usb-storage 3-2.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0.000209] scsi host2: usb-storage 3-2.4:1.0
[  +1.020215] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Realtek  Driver Storage   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  +0.000585] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  +0.000411] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 16000 512-byte logical blocks: (8.19 MB/7.81 MiB)
[  +0.002656] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  +0.000003] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  +0.002631] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  +0.000010] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

`dmesg` output on command `sudo usb_modeswitch -KW -v 0bda -p 1a2b`

```
  +0.009662]  sdb:
[  +0.006413] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[Jul 7 10:05] usb 3-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  +0.223896] usb 3-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.106195] usb 3-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811
[  +0.000003] usb 3-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2.4: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[  +0.000002] usb 3-2.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  +0.000001] usb 3-2.4: SerialNumber: 123456
```

`modinfo`:

```
$ modinfo 8812au
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-109-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko
version:        v4.3.8_12175.20140902
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
```

`dkms status`:

```
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-109-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 4.15.0-109-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 4.15.0-99-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am not the best when it comes to drivers so I could be doing something... very silly...?

Comment: You need a driver for RTL8821CU, perhaps https://askubuntu.com/a/1163018/300665

Comment: @Jeremy31 *SIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHH* really...it had to be the wrong damn driver didnt it... im such a fool... thanks! that was it.

Comment: Since we know that the 8821cu driver works as expected, I'm voting to close as a duplicate. All credit to @Jeremy31.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1082418/300665 so the usb_modeswitch command is run automatically